# Fixing a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to fix a stored procedure that someone else wrote. Basically the proc takes an input value for `GroupingCode` and queries the rest of the tables based on that grouping code.

However it keeps returning null values. Here is the original stored proc:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetWebinars] (@GroupingCode     VARCHAR(MAX) = 'AVM',
                                     @ItemNumber       VARCHAR(MAX) OUT,
                                     @Title            VARCHAR(MAX) OUT,
                                     @SubTitle         VARCHAR(MAX) OUT,
                                     @ShortDescription VARCHAR(MAX) OUT,
                                     @LongDescription  VARCHAR(MAX) OUT,
                                     @ShortImageUrl    VARCHAR(MAX) OUT,
                                     @MedImageUrl      VARCHAR(MAX) OUT,
                                     @LgImageUrl       VARCHAR(MAX) OUT,
                                     @GroupCode        VARCHAR(MAX) OUT)
AS
  SELECT @ItemNumber = prd.itemnumber,
         @GroupingCode = prdtemp.groupingcode,
         @Title = t.brochuredesc,
         @SubTitle = prdtemp.SubTitle,
         @ShortDescription = prdtemp.shortdescription,
         @LongDescription = prdtemp.longdescription,
         @ShortImageUrl = prdtemp.SmallImagePath,
         @MedImageUrl = prdtemp.MediumImagePath,
         @LgImageUrl = prdtemp.LargeImagePath
  FROM   pryor_producttemplate prdtemp
         INNER JOIN pryor_prdItmmst prd
           ON prdtemp.groupingcode = prd.groupcode
         INNER JOIN pryor_topics t
           ON prd.itemnumber = t.topiccode
  WHERE  prdtemp.groupingcode = @GroupingCode
         AND t.country = 'U.S.A'

  SELECT DISTINCT t.city,
                  t.country,
                  t.controlprice,
                  prd.itemnumber
  FROM   pryor_producttemplate prdtemp
         INNER JOIN pryor_prdItmmst prd
           ON prdtemp.groupingcode = prd.groupcode
         INNER JOIN pryor_topics t
           ON prd.itemnumber = t.topiccode
  WHERE  prdtemp.groupingcode = @GroupingCode
         AND t.country = 'U.S.A'
```

I changed the first line and changed

```
@GroupingCode varchar(max) = 'AVM'
```

to

```
@GroupingCode varchar(max),
```

It seemed weird to me that the input value would be hard coded.

Anyway after making the change and executing the proc again I got null values. Is this proc written correctly?

I apologize if this is hard to read. I am not familiar with Markdown.

Thanks.

Oceantrain

Comment: The `= 'AVM'` just means that is the default value if one is not supplied.

Comment: Are there rows with the supplied @GroupingCode in the table pryor_producttemplate? Does the 2nd query return anything if you try to run it in the SQL editor?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried executing it both ways in SQL editor. With the default value set to ='AVM'. When I execute and enter the value 'AVM' I get results. If I enter any other value from GroupingCode column It returns Null. GroupingCode and the ProductTemplate table is filled with healthy data. So I don't understand why I only get resuls when entering 'AVM' when I test the procedure.

Comment: That's a good question Angelo. I have not tried using just the second query to see if that is whats broken. I will try just that second one and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if a value is *not* being supplied for @GroupingCode, then changing

```
@GroupingCode varchar(max) = 'AVM'
```

to

```
@GroupingCode varchar(max)
```

results in @GroupingCode being set to NULL

Might this be the source of your problem?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried executing it both ways in SQL editor. With the default value set to ='AVM'. When I execute and enter the value 'AVM' I get results. If I enter any other value from GroupingCode column It returns Null. GroupingCode and the ProductTemplate table is filled with healthy data. So I don't understand why I only get resuls when entering 'AVM' when I test the procedure.

Comment: If the value was not supplied for a parameter that had no default value defined for it, I'd expect the stored procedure to fail to execute in the first place.